# adding a button programmatically

Tags: ios, button, hierarchy

I add a button programmatically with an external class:

file header:

```
-(UIView*) makeButtonNotification;
```

file method:

```
-(UIView* ) makeButtonNotification{

UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chat-notify.png"];

button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(goChat)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 25.0, 30.0, 30.0);
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

return button;
```

}

this button call goChat method

```
- (void)goChat{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
chat = (chatViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatViewController"];
chat.view.layer.zPosition = 10;


[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:chat];
```

}

i add the view with this code:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:chat];
```

because otherways i have problem with hierarchy

*whose view is not in the window hierarchy!*

i call the method like this:

```
 notificationViewController* notification = [[notificationViewController alloc]init];  
[self.view addSubview:[notification makeButtonNotification]];
```

now the view appear and this is not the problem.

but when appear i have a button make with storyboard for open left panel menu and that not working.

there is some other solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `makeButtonNotification` is creating and returning a UIButton but your return type is set to UIView ? Also, do you have a class property for button ? As you are not creating a local instance in that method ?

Where are you calling this `goChat` method, I assume it's outside of the `appDelegate` ?

Your setting the buttons frames origin to 280 are you sure this is within the bounds of self.view ? what view are you adding it to ?